# RenderScript Android Sample example RenderScript >HelloCompute is not compiling

Tags: android, renderscript

I'd like to do some experiment with renderscript, so I started with the example shipped with the sdk, but unfortunatly I am not able to compile it. 
Is there any extra tool which I might required to compile and build that example, I'd tried to read the doc. but they haven't mentioned anything.

The problem with the Sample project is...

I came to know after building the project eclipse will generate new files in res/raw folder and some files in gen folder, and this files can be used in java files, but this files are **not generating**. can anyone guide me how to solve this errors.

Thanks,

Answer (score 6):

After about three days of struggling with this, I found that the problem was with the project folder structure, when compiling with gradle. This project shows the correct structure:

https://android.googlesource.com/platform/tools/build/+/11086782041b302109e8349e13b8f9d5e305341d/tests/renderscript/

In short, the .rs files should not be together with the java files, but in a separate folder called 'rs' alongside java and res, with the same inside structure, such as "...\HelloRSProject\HelloRS\src\main\rs\com\example\hellors\mono.rs". Also, be sure to add renderscriptTargetApi to the build.gradle file, like so:

```
android {
    compileSdkVersion 17
    buildToolsVersion "18.0.1"

    defaultConfig {
        minSdkVersion 16
        targetSdkVersion 16
        renderscriptTargetApi = 16
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4):

There is a bug in ADT 22. I've already reported it [here](https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=55342)(you can find temporary workaround there, too).

Comment: nice. i was looking for this workaround for a long time. I thought we faced problems before sdk 14.